# How to set nginx conf (403 forbidden page) to pass OWASP security test

Tags: django, nginx, owasp

This is my nginx conf:

```
upstream django {

    server 127.0.0.1:8001; 
}

server {
    listen     80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;  
    charset     utf-8;

    #security
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    location /static {

        alias /usr/share/nginx/mysite/staticfiles;  

    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; 
    }
}
```

And my settings.py :

```
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_FRAME_DENY = True
```

But It still have security problem with static files, What else should I set??

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found as @LinnTroll said ,It seems the the nginx 403 page didn't have security protect. How should I set it??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not django problem. Nginx returns error code (403) for direct access to path like /static/, and directive add_header doesn't work for responses with error codes. If you use nginx version >= 1.7.5, add third parameter 'always' to add_header directive:

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
```

If you have nginx version lower then 1.7.5, i know the following simple ways to solve your problem:

- update nginx to version >= 1.7.5
- enable directive `autoindex on;` for you /static location. (warning: all you static files will be available for anyone, including search engines!)
- add following location before you /static location:

  ```
  location ~* ^/static.*/$ {
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
      # ... you other headers ...
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
      return 200;
  }
  ```

Comment: My version is 1.6.3 .I still not find a solution yet

Comment: Thank you so much. Share with you another method I found : add ````error_page 403 /403;````, ````/403```` is my web page